# check value from SQL to enable textbox and label

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, if-statement

I have a WinForm app in C# in witch i need to hide some textboxes and labels depending on the item selected on the previous form.
I disabled the textboxes and labels in the designer and would make them visible again depending on a value from a SQL table.
The code i have is this one but i cant figure out how to check the value.

```
private void build_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select prumos from dbo.modelos";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var check = dr["prumos"].ToString();
            textBox13.Visible = check == "2";
            textBox18.Visible = check == "2";
            textBox17.Visible = check == "2";
            label16.Visible = check == "2";
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //var check = dr["prumos"].ToString();
        //textBox13.Visible = check == "3";
        //textBox18.Visible = check == "3";
        //textBox17.Visible = check == "3";
        //textBox14.Visible = check == "3";
        //textBox16.Visible = check == "3";
        //textBox15.Visible = check == "3";
        //label16.Visible = check == "3";
        //label20.Visible = check == "3";
        //return;
    }
    con.Close();
```

I also would like to apply an `else if`  so that if the id is 2 ... some textboxes appear, ifthe id is 3... more of them appear.

Can anyone help please,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlReader can check your command values. check this:

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select prumos from dbo.modelos";
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  



  if (dr.HasRows)
   {

         while(dr.Read())
        {
           var check = dr["prumos"].ToString()
            //if "2" then true, else false 
            textBox13.Visible = check == "2";
        }

   }

 else
  {
     //no row return
  }
```

Comment: I think this is perfect, but when i apply the code i get the error:_Invalid read attempt when data is not present._
in the line `var check = dr["prumos"].ToString();`
the thable has data.

Comment: Now i get no error but i lost connection to the DB, i will edit my code above to the new version. 
can you take a look?
thanks for the help

Comment: @MarcIT i just tested it. It works fine on my computer. do you close Reader and Connection after read the value?

Comment: yes, i used the commands  `dr.Close();` and `con.Close();` is this correct?

Comment: The texboxes need to be enabled but not visible for this right?

Comment: if you set any control visibility to false , it does matter enabled or not.

Comment: ok, i changed them to visible, and now all of them appear exept for the selected ones :s
thanks again for the help and pacience ;)

Answer (score 0):

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); is typically used for executing SQL statements that do not return results (like Update Statements).

Use something like this instead:

```
var prumos = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but can you help my with the `if` syntax
i cant seem to get this right. what i want is something like.
`if prumos value from dbo.modelos =2` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select prumos from dbo.modelos";
    int value = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (value == 2) ; //database value prumos =2
    {
        textBox13.Visible = true;
        textBox18.Visible = true;
        textBox17.Visible = true;
        label16.Visible = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (value == 3) ; //database value prumos = 3 
    {
        textBox13.Visible = true;
        textBox18.Visible = true;
        textBox17.Visible = true;
        textBox14.Visible = true;
        textBox16.Visible = true;
        textBox15.Visible = true;
        label16.Visible = true;
        label20.Visible = true;
        return;
    }
```

You could do something similar to what I have shown Above by editing you code.
By using ExecuteScalar() will return you object you can cast it to int or string as per your requirement or the value that is coming from the database and use it in the way I have mentioned above.